# Bluescreen (error code: PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR) after Dell update

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, windows-update, dell-latitude

Really hoping someone can help me. I'm at work and trying to fix one of our laptops. It's Dell Latitude E5450 running Windows 10.

A couple of hours ago (before I got in, unfortunately) it displayed a popup with an update from Dell. My coworker opted to install it and get it out of the way.

It rebooted as part of the update process, and began bluescreening with the error code: PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR.

It does this for a few times until it goes to the recovery menu. I can get into safe mode.

Things I've tried:

- Every available system restore point. They all fail.
- The "startup repair" option in the recovery menu (not sure what its
  called in english, the laptop is in Danish).
- used "sfc /scannow". No errors.
- Re-enabled MS Installer in safe mode and uninstalled the update.

Here are the five latest Minidump files: [minidumps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Yn2m4-z0VhNklqcFczVjgwM1U)

To the best of my knowledge the update was legit.
Nothing looks off in the device manager. There's three disabled devices, but all of them because of safe mode.

Dell support was.. Well, well-meaning and as helpful as they could be. Unfortunately, it seems like I know more than they did and their only solution as "reinstall".

I've tried similiar things with another latop a few months back. System restore worked then, but doesn't now.
I'm really hoping to save reinstalling as an absolutely last resort.
Anybody have any ideas on what could be wrong and what I can try to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at dump with Windbg shows this string `\??\ACPI#INT3400#2&daba3ff&3#{ee27098e-1b22-472a-89d8-5ccce16b1356}`

```
0xffffe681c74469c8 : 0xfffff8009ba8e454 : nt!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite+0x1d4
0xffffe681c7446a18 : 0xfffff8009c15f970 : nt!PnpDeviceClassNotifyList+0xc0
0xffffe681c7446a48 : 0xfffff8009bec9894 : nt!PnpNotifyDeviceClassChange+0x174
0xffffe681c7446ad8 : 0xffffe681c7446b60 : 0xfffff8009bdd5100 : nt!ExNode0
0xffffe681c7446ae8 : 0xfffff8009bf0e6cf : nt!PnpDeviceEventWorker+0x263
0xffffe681c7446b00 : 0xffffe681c7446b60 : 0xfffff8009bdd5100 : nt!ExNode0
0xffffe681c7446b38 : 0xffffa483c20fce18 :  !du "\??\ACPI#INT3400#2&daba3ff&3#{ee27098e-1b22-472a-89d8-5ccce16b1356}"
0xffffe681c7446b58 : 0xfffff8009bdd5280 : nt!ExNode0+0x180
0xffffe681c7446b60 : 0xfffff8009bdd5100 : nt!ExNode0
0xffffe681c7446b70 : 0xfffff8009bf0e46c : nt!PnpDeviceEventWorker
0xffffe681c7446b78 : 0xfffff8009ba846f9 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0xe9
0xffffe681c7446b80 : 0xfffff8009bdd5100 : nt!ExNode0
0xffffe681c7446b98 : 0xfffff8009bdd5280 : nt!ExNode0+0x180
0xffffe681c7446bf8 : 0xfffff8009bdd5280 : nt!ExNode0+0x180
0xffffe681c7446c00 : 0xfffff8009ba84610 : nt!ExpWorkerThread
0xffffe681c7446c08 : 0xfffff8009bad52d5 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x41
0xffffe681c7446c58 : 0xfffff8009bb72c86 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
0xffffe681c7446c70 : 0xfffff8009bad5294 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
```

Which seams to be an ["Intel DPTF Manager" or related driver](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/27726-anyone-know-sure-what-acpi-int3400-2-daba3ff-2-a.html). So look inf this driver was updated [and rollback to older version](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732648.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I've already reinstalled it, so I can't even test if that would work or at least help me somehow.. still, thanks a lot for trying to help :)